# How to change jsp loop element with jQuery ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, foreach

I receive list of feeds from servlets like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${feedList}" var="feed">
    <tr>
        <td><input readonly="readonly" id="feedId"
            value="<c:out value="${feed.id}" />" /></td>
        <td id="feed-name"><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td>
        <td><a
            href="FeedController?action=delete&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>">Delete</a>
        </td>
        <td><a
            href="FeedItemController?action=feedItemListAsc&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>">View</a></td>
        <td><button onclick="openEditDialog('${feed.id}', '${feed.name}' )" >Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Edit button opens modal window and change record name in database with servlets and display new name after renaming on page:

```
$('#renameFeed').click(
        function() {
            var name = $('#feedName').val();
            var id = $('#feedId').val();
            var action = 'edit';

            var data = "feedName=" + name + "&id=" + id
                    + "&action=" + action;

            $.ajax({
                type : "Get",
                url : "FeedController",
                data : data,
            }).done(function() {
            $('#feed-name').text(name);
        });
             $('#mask, .window').hide();
        });
```

It works fine but when you change name of different feeds in a jsp loop  `$('#feed-name').text(name);`every time displays changed name of the first feed in the loop.
Maybe need to add `varStatus="count"` to jsp loop and change name regarding to ${count.index}?
What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's changing the first found element because of `id` selector that you used to identify your cell.
There are multiple ways to do it, I'll give some examples, and you choose what's closer to your overall architecture/convention.

You can add an identifier to you cell

`<td class="feed-name" id='<c:out value="${feed.id}" />' ><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td><!-- use default id attribute -->`

or

`<td id="feed-name" feed-id='${feed.id}' ><c:out value="${feed.name}" /></td> <!-- use custom attribute (not so good since you will not be using 'id' as it should be)-->`

and than you can indetify your cell by :

`$('.feed-name[feed-id="'+ id +'"]').text(name)`

or

`$('#feed-name[feed-id="'+ id +'"]').text(name)`

respectively.

If I had to do it, I'd refactor a little more.

- I'd add an identifier to a row `<tr id='<c:out value="${feed.id}" />'>`
- I'd changed ids to classes in your example `<td id="feed-name">` to `<td class="feed-name">`
- I'd change jQuery selectors to `$('#'+id).find('.feed-name')` to identify respective cell.

Comment: Why do you use '+ id +' in $('.feed-name[feed-id="'+ id +'"]').text(name)?And how to use $('#'+id).find('.feed-name') selector instead $('.feed-name[id="' + id + '"]').text(name);? I works for me when I use id="' + id + '"] instead of feed-id="'+ id +'"

Comment: take a look at https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ on how to use selectors by attributes names/values